# iOS - Entering Table View Editing changes Cell's labels constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When my `UITableView` enter editing mode it pushes the cells content to the right as usual, and updates the constraints on `UILabel` to fit inside the cell.

Upon exiting editing mode, the `UILabel` do not update their layout, and stay bunched up.

How do I layout and update the cell's constraints to match the original layout after exiting editing mode?

Comment: That should be happening automatically. Could there be something in your code that is interfering?

Comment: I dont think so. I just have labels with autolayout@coopersita

Comment: Is textLabel or detailLabel or your custom label?

Comment: its a custom label @Vincent

Comment: Do you add it to the  cell's contentView? Do not add directly to the cell.

Comment: I did added the label in storyboards. So yes, I added it to the cell's content view.@Vincent